# C- Decision function to swap strings or numbers inside array of structs

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct Workers
{
char id[10];
char *fName;
char *lName;
int  yob;
int monthlyHours;
int salary;



}workers;
```

so i have a struct that is filled with workers details.
in the main menu the user enters an option either to :
1.sort by id
2.sort by first name
3.sort by monthly hours
i need to create a decision function which is a pointer function that will sort the struct by the selected option  either by string or by integer.

i wrote a bubble sort function and a swap function but don't have the slightest clue how to make a decision function that can handle all type of sorts

current state of swap function

```
int me_compare(workers *me1, workers *me2) {
int surnameResult;

surnameResult = strcmp(me1->fName, me2->fName);

return surnameResult;
}
```

current state of sort function

```
void sortStruct(workers newWorkers[N], int numOfSort)
{
workers tmp;
workers tmp2;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

int result;
int swapped;
for ( i = 0;( i < N-1); i++)
{
    swapped = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < N-i - 1; j++)
    {
        tmp = newWorkers[j];
        tmp2 = newWorkers[j + 1];
        result = me_compare(&tmp, &tmp2);
        if (result == 1)
        {
            newWorkers[j] = tmp2;
            newWorkers[j + 1] = tmp;
            swapped = 1;
        }
    }
    if (swapped == 0)
        break;

}

}
```

any tips for me how to handle this ?

Comment: Think about what would be different for the different types of sort...and also think about how you'd tell your sort code which one is picked.

Comment: Indent your code. Can't you use `qsort()`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner 
managed it with this pointer function 

 int(*p)(workers, workers); // pointer function that always works with two nodes of the struct
 if (numOfSort==4)
 {
  p = compareNumbers;
 }
 else if (numOfSort==2)
 {
  p = me_compare2;
 }
 else
 {
  p = compareNumbers2;
 }

it will select the needed function based on user input

Answer (score 0):

For a int value we use

```
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
   for(j = 0 ; , j = n-i-1; j++)
   {
       if(value[i]>value[i+1])
           swap(value[i],value[i+1]);
   }
}
```

Similarly for a struct function we can use

```
    if(workers[i]->salary > workers[i+1]->salary)
```

template in c++ is used to write function with generic types but in c we do not have this facility

i suggest you to write two different swap function for both int and char type and in sorting write an additional code to identify if it is char or int and used the swap function function according to this

Comment: May a more experienced coder know how to write generic datatypes function in c but for me i will follow this approach